# Create a foreach function while using a lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, lru

I have created a simulation of a LRU cache which is defined as described bellow:

`unordered_map<string, std::pair<T, std::list<string>::iterator>> mycache;`

Meaning, I also have a data member in the cache class called `list<string> mylist;`

The priorities of the cache to use LRU algorithm is on the `list<string>`.

I need to create a `foreach` function using a lambda function to print out the items (`T objects`) in the cache according to their priorities (**their order in `mylist`**).

I did manage to print-out the items of the map:

```
template class <p>
  void foreach(p func) {
    for (typename std::unordered_map<string, pair<T, list<string>::iterator>>::iterator it = mycache.begin();
         it != mycache.end(); ++it) {
      func(it->second.first);
    }
  }
```

When I tried to do it on the list:

```
 void foreach(const function<void(T&)> func) {
    for (auto key:priorityQueue) {
      pair<T, list<string>::iterator> mypair = mycache.find(key);
      T obj = mypair.first;
      func(obj);
    }
  }
```

This fails to **compile** and says there's an issue with the `mypair`.
error is the following:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<Student, std::_List_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<Student, std::_List_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > >::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<Student, std::_List_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, false, true>}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::pair<Student, std::_List_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’ requested
       pair<T, list<string>::iterator> mypair = mycache.find(key);
```

*Where is my bug?*

Comment: What is the real error message?

Comment: That cannot be the entire error message.

Comment: Add it to your original post.

Comment: The return type of `find` is an iterator not a pair. You have to dereference it. (If it is not `end()`!) See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) for documentation. The object you want should be `mycache.find(key)->second`.

Comment: Please have a look at how to make a [mcve].